# YouTube Data APIのクォータについて

Tags: ios, android, youtube-data-api

現在、多くのYouTube系スマートフォンアプリがありますが、これらはYouTube Data APIを使用しているのでしょうか？
調べてみると、YouTube Data APIには、下記のようにリクエスト数の上限があります。アプリを使う人が増えれば、この上限にすぐ達してしまうと思うのですが、、、、。
それとも、YouTube Data APIは使わずに、WebViewなどを使用しているのでしょうか？

[クォータの使用量](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=ja#quota)

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらから申請することでクオータを拡張することができます。
https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/

この申請フォームは
Cloud Console > API Manager > Overview > Quotas
で YouTube Data API から確認できるリンクにあります。